# MathJax won't render dynamically sized left/right braces (or parentheses, brackets, etc)

Tags: scaling, braces, mathjax

When I try something like:

```
\left\{ x+y = z \\ 2x - 3y = yomamma
```

, MathJax fails to render.  At first I thought it was an issue with my website, but this problem also happens on the official MathJax test page: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html

I've tried other ways of doing it, including:

```
\left{ x+y = z \\ 2x - 3y = yomamma

\left.{ x+y = z \\ 2x - 3y = yomamma

\left\lbrace x+y = z \\ 2x - 3y = yomamma
```

None of these work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mathjax questions are mostly off topic for this site, unless they also apply to tex but that seems to be the case here, you need `\left` `\right` to be in pairs, and may not have `\\ ` between them, so the fragments you show are missing three `\right` commands

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MathJax.

While MathJax shares the same markup language the engine is different

Comment: Where then, would a MathJax question be considered "on-topic"?  Honestly, I had no idea if my problem was syntax-related or engine-related.  That's why I'm asking you guys in the first place.

Comment: @alexw Try superuser.SX or their meta first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It's not clear the layout you want, I offer three possibilities below.
Using LaTeX markup to keep it on topic for this site.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\left\{ x+y = z\right. \\ 
2x - 3y = yomamma
\end{align*}

or

\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 x+y &= z \\ 
  2x - 3y &= yomamma
\end{aligned}\right.
\]

or

\[
\begin{cases}
 x+y = z \\
 2x - 3y = yomamma
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup, the third is what I was going for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks David, you put me on the right path.  What I needed was:

```
\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y = z \\ 2x - 3y = yomamma \end{array}\right.
```

The `\right.` performs the required matching of `\left\{` without actually drawing a closing brace.

`\begin{array}{l}` defines a left-justified array, and gets closed with `\end{array}`.  The `l` (that's a lowercase "L") is an argument to `\begin{array}` that tells it to left-justify.

Comment: `array` is really designed for setting matrices and the like, in particular every entry is in textstyle, for vertically stacked equations you are better with one of the ams alignments as in my answer (which is also supported by mathjax)